# GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers not working in async method?

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection, async-await

I have some unit tests to verify if objects using WeakReferences work correctly. After refactoring these objects to work asynchronously the unit tests fail. This seems to be caused by GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers not working (or working differently?) when using async.

To check this I created a simple WPF app with two buttons, one with a regular Click event and one with an async click event.

When I press the NormalGCTest button "object garbage collected: True" is shown.

But when I press the AsyncGCTest button "object garbage collected: False" is shown.

What is going on? Is there a way to force a full garbage collection in my tests?

```
    private void NormalGCTest(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var temp1 = new object();
        var temp2 = new WeakReference(temp1);
        temp1 = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        temp1 = temp2.Target;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("object garbage collected: {0}", temp1 == null);
    }

    private async void AsyncGCTest(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var temp1 = new object();
        var temp2 = new WeakReference(temp1);
        temp1 = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        temp1 = temp2.Target;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("object garbage collected: {0}", temp1 == null);
        await Task.Delay(0);
    }
```

Comment: Probably the generated closure class still has a reference to temp1 for some reason. I'm not aware of any GC properties that async/await might guarantee. IOW you are not guaranteed by the C# language that temp1 is dead when you call Collect.

Comment: Explicitly calling GC is not advised. You are sure you need it? BTW, AFAIK GC works across all threads (stops all thread while cleaning). Feels a little bit strange to use it combined with async.

Comment: In a console app, both work for me... are you running under the debugger? That may well make a difference.

Comment: Running it locally, I get `True`, `True` - it gets collected both ways

Comment: @PetarRepac This is a *unit test* involving weak references, so of course the GC needs to be called. I don't imagine it's called in the actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, it works fine already - I get `True` / `True`. You could, however, try a few things to clarify what is happening - for example:

```
var wr = CreateWeakReference();
Console.WriteLine("object available: {0}", wr.Target != null);
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
Console.WriteLine("object garbage collected: {0}", wr.Target == null);
```

with

```
static WeakReference CreateWeakReference()
{
    return new WeakReference(new object());
}
```

This uses less locals, which could cause confusion depending on how the compiler translates the C#. It also uses a more aggressive `GC.Collect`.

But important: **stop invoking the garbage collector**. You should almost never do this. Final thought - you might want to avoid `async void`. Yes, I know this is an event-handler, but a nice trick there is to immediate call into a non-`async void` method (using `await` if necessary).

Comment: About your last remarks: I'm perfectly aware of the drawbacks. I use the GC.Collect() only in a unit test and the async void was used to simplify the example.

Comment: Putting the object creation in a static method solved the problem (also in my unit tests).

Comment: @MarcelW then it is almost certainly related to how the compiler chooses to handle locals (including transient locals introduced by the compiler) when translating the method to a state machine (where locals become fields). As such, different compilers (or different compiler options) could have different results.